# asp.net boilerplate (ABP) OdataController and AddODataQueryFilter

Tags: asp.net, odata, aspnetboilerplate

I would like to understand how to configure ABP Odata Module to support the OData Query Filters like `$top`, `$skip` or `$inlinecount`.

When using the standard OData it's just a matter of setting `config.AddODataQueryFilter();` in the Register method of the webapi.

However, I can't find the way to do it with the ABP Odata module.

I assumed that it was already configured out of the box, but on calling the OData service with these filters I see Error 406 returned.

This lead me to believe it's actually not already configured or supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: Can't you do that in `Application_Start`?

Comment: I don't see such an option.
However, Investigating further, I've found out that my problem is not there. The code I was given is MVC based, has webapi routing and now the abpodata... all together. There are probably registration issues. so I need to rephrase my question. Thanks for you good intention :)